# Add class to JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file which generates a bunch of anchors. Now I want to add a class to some of them but dont know how.

Here is my JSON:

```
[
{
    "name":"Home",
    "id":"1",
    "url":""
},
{
    "name":"News",
    "id":"2",
    "url":"news"
},
{
    "name":"About",
    "id":"3",
    "url":"about"
},
{
    "name":"Contact",
    "id":"4",
    "url":"contact"
}
 ]
```

so is there any way to do this? Should I fetch the id and add the class with Jquery?

[UPDATE]

I was thinking in the direction of:

```
    {
    "name":"Contact",
    "id":"4",
    "url":"contact",
    "class" : "some-class"
}
```

inserting the class this way, but that apparently doesnt work...

the code which generates the anchors:

```
{{#each mainmenu}}
 <li>
    <a class="" href="{{this.url}}"><h2>{{this.name}}</h2></a>
 </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The second to last line contains an invalid comma.

Comment: If it's a file, you add the class to it by editing the file. Can you clarify your question? Right now, it's very hard to figure out what you're really asking.

Comment: Can you post the code generating the anchors?

Comment: Have you tried `class="{{this.class}}" href="{{this.url}}"`?

Comment: What does this have to do with jquery?!

Comment: I would not say something obvious but have you parsed the JSON with $.parseJSON? Or if you get json form a ajax call use datatype "json"? and your json response have Content-Type text/json?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your JSON to contain entries of this type:

```
{
    "name":"Contact",
    "id":"4",
    "url":"contact",
    "classname" : "some-class"
}
```

You should also change the code which generates the anchors to use that class:

```
{{#each mainmenu}}
 <li>
    <a class="{{this.classname}}" href="{{this.url}}"><h2>{{this.name}}</h2></a>
 </li>
{{/each}}
```

*Note that using `class` instead of `classname` may fail, because `class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#In_ECMAScript_3) in JavaScript. See Pavlo's comment for more details on when it's safe to use and when it isn't.

Comment: `class` is only [invalid as an Identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Reserved_word_usage), so `var class;` and `function class() {}` are invalid, in other cases you are safe.

Comment: Pavlo thanks!. @SHT how doesn't it work? Just saying it doesn't is not quite helpful.

Comment: @Tibos sorry, well the anchors are not displayed at all when I add the classname attribute in the json file and add it in the code which generates the anchors <a class="{{this.classname}}" href="{{this.url}}"><h2>{{this.name}}</h2></a>

Comment: @SHT What templating engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using BackboneJS + Handlebars + RequireJS